# Why is group_by() appearing not to group anything?

Tags: r, dplyr

i'm dealing with a strange behaviour from group_by() and mutate() recently.
While I already used these functions properly before, it seems that something's going wrong with my desired work today.

I'm looking to calculate the distance between numerous consecutive geographic points overtime, by groups (marked individuals)

Here it how my dataset looks like :

| "DATE" | "lon" | "lat" | "ID_PIT" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "08/07/2016" | -0.616080768410155 | 45.8430975765271 | 43596 |
| "24/02/2018" | -0.632287900326278 | 45.8177515273291 | 43596 |
| "13/08/2018" | -0.616080768410155 | 45.8430975765271 | 43596 |
| "28/09/2020" | -0.68536933637008 | 45.882032720692 | 220217 |
| "22/01/2021" | -0.142898405525702 | 45.6436089508837 | 220217 |
| "31/01/2021" | -0.629911009070587 | 45.7851507139944 | 43596 |
| "30/07/2021" | -0.616080768410155 | 45.8430975765271 | 43596 |

I want to calculate the distance betwwen consecutive points by ID_PIT,
so far I tried using ;

```
a <- Data %>%
  group_by(ID_PIT) %>%
  mutate(dist = c(NA, geosphere::distVincentyEllipsoid(cbind(lon, lat))))  %>%
  ungroup()
```

My result :

| "DATE" | "lon" | "lat" | "ID_PIT" | "dist" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "08/07/2016" | -0.616080768410155 | 45.8430975765271 | 43596 | NA |
| "24/02/2018" | -0.632287900326278 | 45.8177515273291 | 43596 | 3085.80808464715 |
| "13/08/2018" | -0.616080768410155 | 45.8430975765271 | 43596 | 3085.80808464669 |
| "28/09/2020" | -0.68536933637008 | 45.882032720692 | 220217 | 6904.98418513713 |
| "22/01/2021" | -0.142898405525702 | 45.6436089508837 | 220217 | 49831.0971131536 |
| "31/01/2021" | -0.629911009070587 | 45.7851507139944 | 43596 | 41053.013590596 |
| "30/07/2021" | -0.616080768410155 | 45.8430975765271 | 43596 | 6529.74315318872 |

As you can see, the code is running, as it calculates the distance between the successive points, but it seems that group_by does'nt group anything, and therefore the code calculates the distance no matter what "ID_PIT" it is..

I'm not sure what i'm missing here...
Anyone could help me figure this out ?

Thanks !

Comment: You should use `dplyr::summarise()`

Comment: Hi bird, 
Thanks for your reply.

It seems to work with `dplyr::summarise()`, and even with `dplyr::mutate()` (which is better to my as it add the result to my original dataset).

I'm still confused why `dplyr::mutate()` acts different than `mutate()`. Any clue ?

Comment: `dplyr::mutate()` and `mutate()` are the same if you do `library(dplyr)` before.